# Replace the characters in a string

Tags: c#

I have a string result Like

```
Result="\"a3bd2afc-6cd8-4341-803a-30ef096cd5fe\""
```

I want to remove the first  "\ and last \" from the string. and output like
"a3bd2afc-6cd8-4341-803a-30ef096cd5fe".

I just try

```
 Result = Result.Remove(Result.IndexOf("'\'"), 1);
 Result = Result.Remove(Result.LastIndexOf("'\'"), 1);
```

but not getting the required output.

can anyone help. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: those are escape sequence and not just character. your resultant string would just be `"vvccvvcvb"`

Comment: Why not just replace all slashes? `result = result.Replace("\", string.Empty)`? If you are trying to read a GUID (which is what it appears from your sample code), then this will work perfectly.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but 1. remove the single quotes and 2. try to escape the backslash: `"\\"`

Comment: if this is meant to end with parsing a guid, have you tried feeding that guid into the parser as is?

Comment: The backslashes are purely the way to include characters not normally allowed in a string (like double quotes) in a string. They will not be present if you look at the value of the string when the program runs.

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama That will throw an exception.

Comment: @DavidG TryParse wouldn't ;)  in any case, it was a quick thought :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that accepts a list of characters to trim, eg:

```
var newString=oldString.Trim('"');
```

The parameter is actually a parameter array, which means you can pass more than one character, or pass an array you may already have, or one that was created from other input:

```
var newString=oldString.Trim('"','x');
```

or

```
var newString=oldString.Trim(mySeparators);
```

You can trim characters only from the beginning or end using [TrimStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TrimEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx) respectively.

Also note that you should try to avoid creating temporary strings whenever possible. `TrimStart().TrimEnd()` will create a temporary string that has to be garbage collected. When parsing even a moderate file of a few thousand rows that's a lot of wasted memory and especially, CPU. When parsing log files this can be a real killer.

Comment: I didn't downvote but that trimming is not needed at all since `\\` is just the escape character. If OP just prints the `result` variable ... the output will be as expected.

Comment: Check the question again. The OP doesn't want the quotes in the result. Although I've seen so many confused questions about escaped quotes that I started to sanitize them unconciously

Comment: @Rahul OP's code will throw `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: @Rahal You're correct that the OP doesn't need to do anything and just needs to print the string.

Comment: didn't OP said *and output like "a3bd2afc-6cd8-4341-803a-30ef096cd5fe".*? I feel OP has no idea what a escape character is?

Answer (score 2):

> and output like "a3bd2afc-6cd8-4341-803a-30ef096cd5fe".

Those are escape character to escape the `"` and not just character. If you just print your `result` variable you will get a output like `"a3bd2afc-6cd8-4341-803a-30ef096cd5fe"`

Just try the below code block to see

```
        string Result = "\"a3bd2afc-6cd8-4341-803a-30ef096cd5fe\"";
        Console.WriteLine(Result);
```

Answer (score 2):

**There is no backslash in your string!**

Really, there isn't. The `\` is just the escape character for what is following, a double quote: `"`. That way the compiler knows the double quote isn't the end of your string, but just a character in it.

So, the solution is to trim just the double quotes off:

```
Result = Result.Trim('"');
```

Comment: This must be the 3rd question in two days that confuses escaped quotes for two characters. Isn't there a good answer that we can use to quickly close the duplicates or at least avoid typing the same stuff again?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just both \" ?

```
Result = Result.Remove(Result.IndexOf("\""), 1);
Result = Result.Remove(Result.LastIndexOf("\""), 1);
```

Comment: Why use Remove at all when there is a method that can do that already?

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will help:
`Result = Result.Replace('\"', ' ').Trim();`

Comment: Check the other answers. You don't need to escape characters. And you can pass the value to trim to Trim itself, ie `Trim('"')`

Comment: um...yup..that one is better !!